# How do you check if a variable equals text in C?

Tags: linux, c

How do I check if a variable equals some text? For example:
If I inputted "Hi" with `scanf`, then how could I check if the "Hi" was something else inputted.
I made a program but it has errors.

The errors:

```
feel.c: In function ‘main’:
feel.c:9:13: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘float’ and ‘char *’)
  if ( value == "Linux mood!" ) {
             ^
feel.c:12:13: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘float’ and ‘char *’)
  if ( value == "So sad." ) {
             ^
feel.c:15:13: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘float’ and ‘char *’)
  if ( value == "Happy!" ) {
             ^
feel.c:18:2: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
  else {
  ^
```

I use float for my variables.

Comment: It's off-topic for this site, but read about `strcmp`, `strncmp` etc... (try `man strcmp` on the terminal). Besides, what are you using `float` for? It doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: Um, I'm using msys2 for windows and I can't install strcmp, neither there is a man page for it. Pacman is installed on msys2. I'm using float for my variables.. if you don't know what float is, go and read a web page about float. It is a way of storing variables.

Comment: @Keanu73 It's a way of storing *numbers*. I'm quite sure Renan knows what they are, but why would you be comparing floats with random non-numeric strings

Comment: Use the `strcmp` function. And show your code.

Comment: How can you "not install strcmp"? it is part of the C standard library

Comment: If you're using msys2 for windows, why is the question tagged with linux ?!

Answer (score 2):

Float is for storing numbers not strings. You should use char* for storing strings. The other problem is, you can't compare C-style strings with == operator. You have to use strcmp function.

strcmp is part of C library. It is not something you can install.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    char buff[20]; //Note that input can be only 19 characters
    scanf("%s", buff);

    if(!strcmp(buff, "Hello"))
    {
        printf("They are equal!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("They are not equal!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be complete you really should also #include <string.h>

Comment: @wurtel well I was able to compile it with gcc. Anyway added #include <string.h>

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!strcmp(text, "hi")) {
    printf("happy to get a hi");
}
else {
    printf("why don't you say a hi");
}
```